# UV wrap Eye Img on sphere

Tags: uv, shaders, image

I have this img and I want to correctly texture a sphere with it. I have minimal no knowledge of UV unwrapping. I want to apply it to either half the sphere or to both halves. I tried making a seam to split it in half then unwrap it but I either did it wrong or it didn't work.

[image]

Help : )

Comment: If you want to use UV mapping but have no idea how it actually works, I would strongly recommend watching a few tutorials on this topic, since this site is not for giving tutorials but rather answering specific questions. So, for example, if you would tell us how you tried to unwrap your model or show a screenshot of what the resulting UV map looks like...

Comment: I did it. I mirorred it then made a seam in the middle and tweaked it on the img and it worked